# Stacking triangles with Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to draw 4 differently colored triangles on top of each other. I've figured out how to draw 4 next to each other, but I don't manage to get them on top of each other.  This is my code:

```
import turtle
import math
from random import randint

otto = turtle.Turtle()

def repeat_triangle(t, l):
    setcolor(t, 1)
    for i in range(4):
        t.color(randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))
        t.begin_fill()
        t.fd(100) 
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(100)
        otto.end_fill()


otto.shape('turtle')
repeat_triangle(otto, 80)

turtle.mainloop()
turtle.bye()
```

Otto is the name of my turtle. setcolor is a function I wrote to assign random colors. Also, could you tell me how to draw a 3x3 pile of triangles? Thanks a lot. I'm using jupyter notebooks so it might have some differences to regular Python. Image reference can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HztrG.png)!

Comment: Can you provide us with a picture of what the end result is supposed to look like? Either way I don't think this question belongs here

Comment: sorry I don't know where else to post it. I'm a noob... picture is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example of better living through *stamping* instead of *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random

TRIANGLE_EDGE = 100
CURSOR_EDGE = 20

TRIANGLE_HEIGHT = TRIANGLE_EDGE * 3 ** 0.5 / 2

def repeat_triangle(turtle, repetitions):
    for _ in range(repetitions):
        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(TRIANGLE_HEIGHT)

screen = Screen()

otto = Turtle('triangle', visible=False)
otto.penup()
otto.setheading(90)
otto.shapesize(TRIANGLE_EDGE / CURSOR_EDGE)

repeat_triangle(otto, 4)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Also, this code may be incorrect, depending on which variant of turtle you're using:

```
t.color(randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))
```

The turtle that comes with Python defaults to a `float` from 0 to 1 -- if you want to use an `int` from 0 to 255 you have to request such via:

```
turtle.colormode(255)
```

A simple rework of your *drawing* code to stack the triangles could be:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def repeat_triangle(t, length):
    height = length * 3 ** 0.5 / 2

    for _ in range(4):
        t.color(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))

        t.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(3):
            t.fd(length)
            t.lt(120)

        t.end_fill()

        t.sety(t.ycor() + height)

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

otto = Turtle('turtle')
otto.penup()

repeat_triangle(otto, 100)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly for me. (Both, but the last one is more like I'm expected to do it)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this perhaps:

```
import turtle
import math
from random import randint

otto = turtle.Turtle()

def repeat_triangle(t, l):
    for i in range(3):
        t.color(randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))
        t.begin_fill()
        t.fd(100) 
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(100)
        #added code starts here
        t.lt(180) #turn 180 (reverse direction)
        t.fd(50) #go halfway
        t.lt(60) #turn downwards and start drawing 
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(120)
    t.fd(100) #finishing after the loop
    t.lt(120)
    t.fd(100)
    #added code finishes here
    otto.end_fill()

otto.shape('turtle')
repeat_triangle(otto, 80)

turtle.mainloop()
turtle.bye()
```

Comment: I did run it, it worked fine for me. I used an online editor for it though, sorry

Comment: Don't be sorry -- the OP may have done the same as you and I made an incorrect assumption.  Which online editor?  Also note that in `repeat_triangle()` it's passed a turtle `t` but ends up using `otto` instead  on `end_fill()` -- an error in the OP's original code.  And then there's that unused second argument...

Comment: I didn't even notice the change in the name haha. I used this online website to test it, should work there https://trinket.io/python

Comment: I ran it too, worked also good for me, but it didn't fill all the triangles. Could be because of some errors I had in my original code though...